# How does a hardware interrupt trigger software handlers without any prior setup

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, atmel, microchip, firmware

I am currently learning about processor interrupts, and have run into some confusions. From what I understand, a processor has a set of external interrupts for peripherals. That way manufactures can provide a way to interrupt the processor via their own peripherals. I know that with this particular processor (ARM Cortex M0+) that once an external interrupt line is triggered, it will go to it's vector table and corresponding interrupt request offset and (I could be wrong here) will execute the ARM thumb code at that address.

And if I understand correctly, some processors will look at the value at said IRQ address, which will point to the address of the interrupt handler.

**Question 1**

While learning about the ARM Cortex M0+ vector table, what is the thumb code doing at that address? I am assuming it is doing something like setting the PC register to the interrupt handler address, but that is just a stab in the dark.

**Question 2**

Also the only way that I have found so far to handle the EIC interrupts is to use this following snippet

```
void EIC_Handler() {
  // Code to handle interrupt
}
```

I am perplexed how this function is called without setup or explicit reference to it in my actual c code. How does the program go from vector table look up to calling this function?

EDIT #1:

I was wrong about the vector table containing thumb code. The vector table contains addresses to the exception handlers.

EDIT #2:

Despite getting the answer I was looking for, my question apparently wasn't specific enough or was "off-topic", so let me clarify.

While reading/learning from **multiple resources** on how to handle external interrupts in software, I noticed every source was saying to just add the code snippet above. I was curious how the interrupt went from hardware, all the way to calling my `EIC_Handler()` without me setting anything up other than defining the function and the EIC. So I researched what a vector table is and how the processor will go to certain parts of it when different interrupts happen. That still didn't answer my question, as I wasn't setting up the vector table myself, yet my `EIC_Handler()` function was still being called.

So somehow at compile time, the vector table had to be created and the corresponding IRQ handle pointing to my `EIC_Handler()`. I searched through 
a good amount of SAML22 and Cortex M0+ documentation (and mis-read that the vector table contained thumb code) but couldn't find anything on how the vector table was being set up, which is why I decided to look for an answer here. And I got one!

I found that the IDE (Atmel studio) and the project configuration I had chosen came along with a little file defining weak functions, implementation of the reset handler, and the vector table. There was also a custom linker script grabbing the addresses to the functions and putting them into the vector table, which if a weak function was implemented, it would point to that implementation and call it when the appropriate interrupt request occurred.

Comment: You are in urgent need of a textbook or a good course at your local university. Sorry, but stack overflow is not a tuturing site; your question is way too broad. Good news is all information can be found in the documentation. Don't try learning solely from obscure online sites like youtube videos.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I would have to disagree that the question is too broad. It was two questions about how the interrupts and vector tables **specifically** work in the Cortex M0 and the SAM library.

Comment: you need to look at the arm cortex-m0+ technical reference manual and the armv6-m architectural reference manual.  the vector table is covered there.  yes it is a list of addresses that point to code.  let the toolchain do the work for you.  make a list of labels generally in assembly language but its just  a list of data not really code.  then the tool fills in the addresses for you.   the handler needs to "handle" the interrupt.  resolve the problem. clear the interrupt all along the processor generally peripheral toward processor.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for the comment! Yeah moving forward I'll definitely just let the toolchain do the heavy lifting, but I wanted to learn and understand what was going on under the hood.

Comment: you have the rough idea.  As documented by arm the vector table is a list of addresses at known locations (reset handler address 0x00000004 for example).  The lsbit has to be set,  so a handler at address 0x1000 needs an entry 0x1001, use the tools right and they do that (goes back to the arm/thumb interworking addressing).  Interrupts are not special to arm/cortex-m.  Each architecture (arm, mips, 8051, x86, etc) has their own nuances, and worse with purchased cores like arm mips or homebrew like 8051 and z80, the chip vendor may wrap more around the core that is different per chip vendor.

Comment: thus clearing from the peripheral to the core, some designs may have one or more intermediate layers that latch the interrupt.  But despite saying that you need to get a feel for that chip design.  Look at the chip vendor examples although understand those were likely not written by their A Team (the code should bother you as you read it, reduce your faith in that library).  Despite that thats the library they support and ideally the library works well enough on that chip/family.

Comment: my best advice is poll as much as you can, start with the peripheral poll your way through how its interrupts work and are cleared, then release that to the next layer in, poll that interrupt controller, learn how to clear it, repeat until all the way to the core.  then you know most of what you need to know to clear/handle the interrupt in the handler, other than the core specific items that are specific to interrupt the core or that are different when polling vs interrupting the core.  Rather than trying to learn all of that within a handler

Comment: The m0 and m0+ are pretty good cores to start with.  I find the STM32's the least frustrating. Atmel makes good stuff though or did before being bought by Microchip, will see if that continues.  I fully understand why for example the uart runs off of a different clock and you have to poll busy bits before communicating with it.  Other vendors will do that for you in logic.  YMMV...Its all part of the fun though if you dont enjoy it even a little bit then just use vendor libraries and hope they get it right enough.  If you do enjoy it buy chips from various vendors and have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Cortex M0 (and other cortexes? corticies?) the vector table doesn't contain thumb code, it is a list of addresses of functions which are the implementation of your exception handlers.

When the processor gets an exception it first pushes a stack frame (`xPSR`, `PC`, `LR`, `R12`, `R3-R0`) to the currently active stack pointer (`MSP` or `PSP`), it then fetches the address of the exception handler from the vector table, and then starts running code from that location.

When there is a `POP` instruction which loads the `PC`, or a `BX` instruction from within the exception handler the processor returns from the exception handler, it destacks the stack frame which was pushed and carries on executing from where it left off. This process is explained in the [Cortex M0+ User Guide - Exception Entry And Exit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/Babefdjc.html)

For question 2, the vector table in the Cortex M0/M0+ is usually located at address 0x00000000. Some Cortex M0/M0+ implementations allow remapping of the vector table using a vector table offset register within the system control block, others allow you to remap which memory is available at address 0x00000000.

Depending on which tool set/library you're using there are different ways of defining the vector table, and saying where it should live in memory.

There are usually weakly linked functions with the name of the exceptions available for your microcontroller, which when you implement them in your source files are linked instead of the weak functions, and their addresses get put into the vector table.

I have no experience with Atmel based ARMs, but @Lundin in the comments says the vector table is located in a "startup_samxxx.c" file. If you've started from scratch it is up to you to ensure you have a suitable vector table, and it's located in a sensible place.

Comment: Regarding Q2, the vector table is often found in some obscure linker file, neither written in C nor assembler, but in some custom linker script syntax.

Comment: I have seen that with some of the MIPS based Microchip PICs, but all the ARMs I've worked with from various vendors have worked as I described. I will leave the answer as it is, thanks for your comment though, @Lundin, it will add clarity if that is the OP's case.

Comment: In case of Atmel ARM (now Microchip), you'll find the vector table in some .c file "startup_samxxx.c", with a non-standard, gcc-flavoured C syntax. In case of NXP ARM (NXP-NXP and NXP-Freescale), it's usually some custom linker script. And so on. It's far from standardized.

Comment: I have updated my answer for question 2, thanks again for your comments, @Lundin

Comment: @Colin thank you for your answer, it cleared up those questions for me. Let's say that the vector table is not remapped/changed. What are the list of addresses in the vector table? I can't seem to find an answer in the Cortex M0+ documentation. Is that why you said "it is up to you to ensure you have a suitable vector table"? Is there a default "implementation" of the vector table, or is it entirely up to the user of the processor to implement?

Comment: @Colin and for some clarification, when I asked "what are the list of addresses in the vector table", I am not meaning the address of where the vector table is or parts of the vector table, but the actual values within them.

Comment: @pidizzle You need to look in two places, the first 16 entries are defined by the processor, follow the link in my answer and look at the vector table section to see them, the rest are implementation defined and will be documented in your microcontroller manual.

Comment: @Colin fantastic! I went through the exception model portion and things are starting to really tick. I even found a part where it explicitly says that exception numbers 16+ are implementation specific. Much appreciated! Documentation is King!